# C++ Type alias error: expected unqualified-id before 'using'

Tags: c++, templates, alias, typedef, typename

There are numerous resources explaining how to do Type aliasing, but clearly I am missing something. I am trying to create a map alias. When debugging I want my `Map_t` to be the standard library `map` since it is easier to see what it contains, and when not debugging I want it to be `btree::btree_map` since it uses less memory.

To do this I tried the following:

```
#if DEBUG
#include <map>
template<typename U, typename V>
using Map_t = map<typename U, typename V>;  // <--- Error on this line
#else
#include "btree_map.h"
template<typename U, typename V>
using Map_t = btree::btree_map<typename U,typename V>;  // <--- Error on this line
#endif
```

When compiling I get the error `error: expected unqualified-id before 'using'`. I've tried several variations of the above with no success. Thanks in advance for your comments.

UPDATE:
I feel I may have made this a little confusing be including the btree portion. SO let me expand a little. If I declare my types as say either

```
btree::btree_map<int, int> mymap;
```

or

```
map<int, int> mymap;
```

all is fine. But just trying to introduce

```
template<typename U, typename V>
using Map_t = map<U, V>;

Map_t<int, int> mymap;
```

leads the the error.

Comment: That is a good question. I was under the impression that I was, but I may not be. This is compile command: `g++ -c -g -DDEBUG  -std=c++0x ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is slightly wrong. You need

```
template<typename U, typename V>
using Map_t = map<U, V>;
```

As for the `btree` segment, it depends on the details of `btree`. If it is a namespace with a class template called `btree_map`, then you need

```
template<typename U, typename V>
using Map_t = btree::btree_map<U, V>;
```

If it is a class template with an inner type, then you may need something like

```
template<typename U, typename V>
using Map_t = typename btree<U,V>::btree_map;
```

Comment: I have tried these suggestion, but I am still getting the same error.

Comment: @KerrekSB Actually, I can't make much sense out of `btree`, but if it is a class template some more fixes are needed. See edit.

Comment: I may have muddied the water by including the btree stuff. Everything is fine if you simply declare with `map<U,V>` or `btree::btree_map<U,V>`. The `using Map_t = map<U, V>` bit is still giving me the error.

Comment: @dseiple It could be that your compiler doesn't support this. It is valid C++11. See http://ideone.com/dZcIIT

Comment: I'm using `g++ (GCC) 4.4.7` with the `-std=c++0x` flag. Could it be the version I have doesn't support this even with the C++11 flag set?

Comment: @dseiple That is quite likely. [According to **GCC**](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html) it is only supported from 4.7 onwards.

Comment: Yes, I can see that in your link. It appears I need to upgrade to do this.